# When I fetch an object from Rails and print it out in the terminal, it returns its ID, but not when converted to JSON. Any clue why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, jsonresponse

Here's the relevant code.

This is a custom method I'm using.

/app/controllers/prep_sheets_controller.rb

```rb
  def create_back_right
    @back_sheet = PrepSheet.new().new_back_right
    puts '-----------------------------------------'
    puts @back_sheet
    puts "this is the back sheet id below"
    puts @back_sheet[:id]

    if @back_sheet
      render json: @back_sheet
      # normally I have a render :show template, but it fails because the id returns as null.
    else
      render plain: "nope"
    end
  end
```

/app/models/prep_sheet.rb

```rb
class PrepSheet < ApplicationRecord

  def new_back_right
    self.assign_time_and_date
    self.category = 'Back Fridge'
    self.subcategory = 'Right'
    self.save!
    items = self.create_prep_items_back_right
    create_relations(self, items)
    self.save!
    puts self[:id]
    return self
  end

  def create_prep_items_back_right
    items = PrepItem.create!([
    ... #it's just Item Objects, this part is fine. 
    ])
    return items
  end
```

/config/routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 scope :api, defaults: { format: :json } do     
...
    post 'back_bar_prep_sheets/new_right' => 'prep_sheets#create_back_right'
... 
  end
end
```

The terminal when I run the method:
[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBjgM.png)

The Postman response:
[Postman Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9pKC.png)

I was troubleshooting why my React frontend wasn't recieving the Prep Sheet Object normally, but it turned up as null because the :id attribute was null. So I isolated the problem and saw it was a backend problem, occurring when I render @back_sheet to json.

I'm able to recall its id fine before hand, as seen in the terminal, and it shows up in my database with its id. However, no matter if I try rendering it to json manually using 'render json' or using a template, its id doesn't seem to show up. The object itself is saved once it has been created, and saved once item relations are created.

Any idea as to why the id won't persist to json?

Comment: What rails version? Doe you have an `as_json` method in `PrepSheet`? What does `@back_sheet.id` return?

Comment: Do you have some api framework or json utility that is possibly stripping the id from  a PrepSheet instance when it uses to_json?

Comment: I'm really baffled, so let's try to work and find a solution. Would id print correctly if you used `puts @back_sheet.id` instead of square brackets? Do you have a `id` method defined in `PrepSheet` by any chance?

Comment: Try using `pry`. What is the result of `show-source @back_sheet.id`? Probably it is overridden by another thing.

Comment: @engineersmnky Currently Rails 7.0.8. I do not have an `as_json` method in `PrepSheet`. Testing `@back_sheet.id` results in it yielding nothing.

Comment: @dbugger Unfortunately I don't believe so - I have another controller that fetches json just fine with no issues. I suspect it might be my custom methods, but I'm not sure what about them is causing the issue.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel From the comment to @engineersmnky, `id` doesn't print at all with `@back_sheet.id`, I'm guessing because of strong params. I just have an `attr_reader` method on `id`, but no avail.

Comment: @waza You'll have to forgive me, it's my first time using pry in a Ruby on Rails backend c ontext, it sems to have an `uninitialized constant ApplicationController` error when I try to load the `prep_sheets_controller.rb` into pry. Entering `show-source @back_sheet.id` by itself also throws an error. I'll look into that method. Thanks!

Comment: @nat `@back_sheet.id` being `nil` is your issue. Why this is occurring cannot be determined from the current post.

Comment: @waza I was able to access it when I inserted `binding.pry` into the method - still no dice, unfortunately. `.show-source` and `.show_source` both come up as undefined methods for just the `@back_sheet` instance. However, entering `@back_sheet` in pry yields in fetching the object correctly, with id.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you! Any other information or context that's need to help determine?

Comment: Very difficult to say. Have you overwritten the `id` method in your `PrepSheet` class? What do you get if you type `PrepSheet.new.method(:id).source_location`? Is `id` a primary_key on the table? What does `PrepSheet.primary_key` return?

Comment: @engineersmnky Solved it! Turns out it was the `attr_reader` in my `PrepSheet` model that was wigging the code out. Once that was deleted, smooth sailing. I had a suspicion when I saw something about '[if you have] a attr_reader :id, Rails will pick up the id as a parameter to SQL conditional clause vs using the defined serialization method.' Link here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48242

Answer (score 0):

Oh jeez, I fixed it. Turns out (not sure exactly why) it was the attr_reader for the id in the `prep_sheet.rb` model that was bugging it out. Once it was deleted, it was smooth sailing. Thank you all for your time and effort!

I had my suspicions reading this link on github: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/48242

Comment: `attr_reader :id` will generate a method akin to `def id; @id; end`; however, model attributes are not individual instance variables but instead maintained in the `attributes` hash (which is why) `[:id]` worked. The `id` method in ActiveRecord is actually defined as `_read_attribute(@primary_key)` so when you overwrote this with `attr_reader` the instance variable `@id` is always `nil`. The JSON conversion was then trying to call `id` on your object and that is what resulted in the JSON representation you were seeing.